# PHP/Laravel Time Feld Required

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-5, time

I have a Laravel project that manages users and stuff like that. I'm storing data entered in a time form (time format), however, it keeps telling me that the time field is required even if I filled it.

**Model part of the object**

```php
<?php

protected $fillable = ['name', 'timee'];

public $validationMessages;

public function validationRules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'timee' => 'required|time',
    ];
}
```

**Time form in edit and create.blade.php**

```php
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('timee', '* enter time :') !!} 
    {!! Form::time('timee',null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    {{ $errors->first('timee') }}
</div>
```

**Migration**

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('reminds', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->time('timee');
    });
}
```

Each time I try to save it, it keeps telling me that the `timee` field is required even if I fill it. I don't get it, everything seems correct to me, thank you.

Comment: you have made that field required in validation please remove required from the validations 'timee' => 'required|time', instead just write 'timee' => 'time'.

Comment: Because it needs to be required, removing the required validation doesnt fix my problem it just hide it.

Comment: all my other forms are using {!! Form} without any problems

Comment: check you getting timee before validation with this : `$request->timee`

Comment: What is the output of Form::time(); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use laravel date validation

```
'timee' => 'required|date_format:H:i'
```

for more validation rules look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-date

Comment: what are you passing? can you `dd($request->get('timee'));` and see what you get

Comment: where do I put that line?

Comment: in your controller or whereever you are checking for validation. One more thing why can you not save the whole date and time rather then only time. Laravel uses carbon and you can format the date and time format as you wish

Comment: I have already a function that create a date list. I found out that my controller might be the problem since it never store the time in the create/store function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160462/discussion-between-usrnotfound-and-martin-b).

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks okay to me. I think error comes because of **database column type** might miss match. You should either use `varchar` or `datetime` type.
If you have a column type in `datetime` then please check your format. You can `use Carbon` to change `date` format.

Comment: you can see in my post the database migrations , the timee column is  $table->time('timee'); so in time format. should i change the migrations to datetime format instead of just time